# hash unicode string in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I try to hash some unicode strings:

```
hashlib.sha1(s).hexdigest()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-81: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

where `s` is something like:

> œ∑¡™£¢∞§¶•ªº–≠œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπ“‘åß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬…æΩ≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥÷åйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбююю..юбьтијџўќ†њѓѕ'‘“«««\dzћ÷…•∆љl«єђxcvіƒm≤≥ї!@#$©^&*(()––––––––––∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆•…÷ћzdzћ÷…•∆љlљ∆•…÷ћzћ÷…•∆љ∆•…љ∆•…љ∆•…∆љ•…∆љ•…љ∆•…∆•…∆•…∆•∆…•÷∆•…÷∆•…÷∆•…÷∆•…÷∆•…÷∆•…÷∆•…

what should I fix?

Comment: Is this a Unicode string at all?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Apparently `hashlib.sha1` isn't expecting a `unicode` object, but rather a sequence of bytes in a `str` object. Encoding your `unicode` string to a sequence of bytes (using, say, the UTF-8 encoding) should fix it:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> s = u'é'
>>> hashlib.sha1(s.encode('utf-8'))
<sha1 HASH object @ 029576A0>
```

The error is because it is trying to convert the `unicode` object to a `str` automatically, using the default `ascii` encoding, which can't handle all those non-ASCII characters (since your string isn't pure ASCII).

A good starting point for learning more about Unicode and encodings is the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html), and this [article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: +1 Python3 correctly raises `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Answer (score 5):

Use encoding format `utf-8`,  Try this easy way,

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha256(str(random.getrandbits(256)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
'cd183a211ed2434eac4f31b317c573c50e6c24e3a28b82ddcb0bf8bedf387a9f'
```

Answer (score 0):

You hash `bytes`, not `strings`. So you gotta know what bytes you really want to hash, for example an utf8 memory representation of the string or a utf16 memory representation of the string, etc.

Comment: This probably should have been posted as comment to the question, not as an answer since it doesn't provide the original author's request, namely: what should be fixed?