# A Confusing Case in Python

Tags: python, pyqt4

Im new to pyqt and there is something i didnt get.I made an app using hashlib and of course gui with pyqt.

```
 self.pushButton.connect(self.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.clickedButton)
```

and click button:

```
def clickedButton(self):
        if self.comboBox.currentText() == "MD5":
            self.MD5(self.lineEdit.text())
```

and MD5:

```
 def MD5(self,text):
        self.hash = hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest()
        self.textEdit.setText(self.hash)
```

the result for "hello":
a6f145a01ad0127e555c051d15806eb5

No error.It looks ok.But trying same thing on python shell:

```
 >>> print hashlib.md5("hello").hexdigest()
 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
 >>>
```

is this an error or why am i getting different results?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the strings are the same?

Comment: definitely they are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing to `md5` a `QString`, not a regular Python string. From some experimentation, I can see that both a regular string and a unicode string in Python produce the same result - from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292273/hash-unicode-string-in-python) i can tell that it tries to convert the unicode version to a sequence of "narrow" characters using the `ascii` codec.

```
>>> print hashlib.md5("hello").hexdigest()
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
>>> print hashlib.md5(u"hello").hexdigest()
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

The `QString`, instead, gets hashed differently, as in your program:

```
>>> a=PyQt4.QtCore.QString("hello")
>>> print hashlib.md5(a).hexdigest()
a6f145a01ad0127e555c051d15806eb5
```

although its UTF-8 or Latin 1 representation (both of which are the same as the output of the `ascii` codec, since we are dealing only with alphabetic characters) are hashed the same way as Python strings:

```
>>> print hashlib.md5(a.toUtf8()).hexdigest()
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
>>> print hashlib.md5(a.toLatin1()).hexdigest()
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

Probably what's happening here is that the hashing algorithm is working on the internal representation of the `QString`, which is UTF-16, which obviously differs from the UTF-8 representation, producing different outputs.

Thus, the lesson here is that before performing any hashing on text you have to choose explicitly its encoding before passing it to the hashing function - which works just with bytes - since [there ain't no such thing as plain text](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text.html).

---

***Edit***: it's not working on the UTF-16 representation (otherwise you would get the same result with

```
>>> print hashlib.md5(u'hello'.encode('utf_16')).hexdigest()
25af7f84a93a6cf5cb00967c60910c7d
```

) but on something else; still, the point is that `hashlib` isn't thought to work with `QString`, so it produces some "strange" output. Again, before using it convert the `QString` to a narrow string in some adequate encoding.